# How to change background of Windows 8 Startscreen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I was a big time user of Windows 7 untill switched to Windows 8.  I had customized the login screen for Windows 7 and Microsoft had a nice Registry switch to do so.  I am looking for a similar way to change background of the start screen and also the login screen where you answer the password **without using any 3rd party software**

Basically I want to know if there's some hidden toggle for that in the OS somewhere and that anyone is aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Put mouse on the top right of the screen, when the charms (?) menu shows up click settings, then click "Change PC Settings". You will now have the ability to modify the lock screen. Note that Windows 8 has two different Control Panels, I don't know why. Infact it irritates me because some features work in standard control panel while others only work in metro. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You can try Decor8 for $4.99. More info here http://www.neowin.net/news/techspot-how-to-change-the-start-screen-background-in-windows-8 and if you keep reading in the comments there are ways to do it for free although slightly more involved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andreas though I am specifically searching for ways to do it without any 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

How to Change Lock Screen in Windows 8 with a Custom Image :

First of all copy all your favorite pictures to Sample Pictures folder “C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures” .

Now open metro Control Panel on Start Screen where Personalize section already selected on left here your current lock screen is shown with 4 sample lock screens at the bottom provided by Windows.

Browse for Pictures, here all pictures we added in Sample Pictures folder are displayed, select any one and click Choose Picture and you’re done.

Source: http://techdows.com/2012/01/set-custom-image-as-lock-screen-background-in-windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way without using 3rd party tools or hacking system files.

Win8 seems to be about removing users choice.

Comment: It is rumored that Blue will bring more customisability

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Microsoft account  or Hotmail you can change your log on windows 8 to Microsoft account and you will see your email picture in your log on in windows

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the start screen background in win 8 without any third party software.
You can try decor 8, it is a good software and doesn't slows down your system.
But if you dont want to use that too then I reccomend you to upgrade to win 8.1 because it gives you the option to set the desktop wallpaper as start screen background. Also you can set a custom image as lock screen

Comment: I am talking about the background color of the screen before you login not only of the screen when you press `start`.

Comment: In Windows 8.1 you can change the startscreen's background, yes but how to do the same for the prelogin screen (i.e. one before you login).  Is there any option in 8 or 8.1 to do that?

Comment: Well if you mean the screen which asks for password or shows your account picture and says welcome, then that can be easily changed in win 8.1 by opening the charm bar while you are in start menu and clicking on personalize. There you can select your background color and accent color. And if you mean the very first boot up screen which shows windows logo then you can try many windows boot logo changing softwares they are quite easy to find on Google.